# Firebase Javascript: How to create list of value

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

This is the list of data in my firebase:

[image: This is my firebase data]

This is my source code:

```
var keys = firebase.database().ref().child('seller').once('child_added').then(function(datakey){

    var makeList = firebase.database().ref('seller/' + datakey.getKey() +'/sellerName').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var nama = snapshot.val();
        var button = $('<a href="#sellerLogin" class="ui-btn ui-shadow big" data-transition="pop" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px";">'+ nama + '</a>');
        button.appendTo('#sellerList'); 
    });

});
```

My problem is, when I execute it, it only create a button element for Seller Name 'Miraak' only but not 'Khajiit'. Like this:

[image]

I want it to create a list of buttons based on the number of seller in my firebase. Like currently I have two seller, Miraak and Khajiit, I want both of them to appear as button list.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing title.

Comment: You can always change it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var keys = firebase.database().ref().child('seller/').once('value').then(function(datakey){
        datakey.forEach(function(data){
            var nama = data.val();
            var button = $('<a href="#sellerLogin" class="ui-btn ui-shadow big" data-transition="pop" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px";">'+ nama.sellerName + '</a>');
            button.appendTo('#sellerList'); 
        });
    });
```

Nevermind, I found the solution to my problem. Thank you.